# Ember.js Action error: "Nothing handled the event"

Tags: ember.js

I'm working on my first Ember.js app, and though I have a template loading, when I attempt to invoke an action that I've defined in the controller, I'm getting an error: "Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'showNew'." I'm not sure if I've set up the route and controller incorrectly, or if I'm missing something else.

./router.js:

```
Seanchai.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource("stories", function(){
    this.route('new');
  });
});

Seanchai.StoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    Seanchai.Story.find();
  }
});


Seanchai.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

./controllers/stories_controller.js:

```
Seanchai.StoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({    

  showNew: function() {
    this.set('isNewVisible', true);
  }
});
```

./templates/stories/index.hbs:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each stories}}
      {{view Seanchai.ShowStoryView storyBinding="this"}}
    {{/each}}
    {{#if isNewVisible}}
      <tr>
        <td>*</td>
        <td>
          Test
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/if}}
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="commands">
  <a href="#" {{action showNew}}>New Story</a>
</div>
```

If I move the action into a router, like so, it works, but based on the documentation it looks like I should be able to do this in the controller.

updated ./router.js:

```
Seanchai.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource("stories", function(){
    this.route('new');
  });
});

Seanchai.StoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    Seanchai.Story.find();
  },
  events: {
    showNew: function() {
      this.set('isNewVisible', true);
    }
  }
});


Seanchai.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});
```

I'm obviously missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your `showNew` event is not firing on the controller because you have a `stories.index` template so you should hook into the correspondent controller which should be a `StoriesIndexController`:

```
Seanchai.StoriesIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({    
  showNew: function() {
    this.set('isNewVisible', true);
  }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. I thought that, in absence of a StoriesIndexController, it would roll up to actions in the StoriesController. So, I would need a stories.hbs template being what's rendered to use a StoriesController, and otherwise I'd use a controller matching that templates action? Just want to make sure I understand the model.

Comment: basically, when you have a resource like `this.resource('stories')` defined on your router then you need an additionally `index` route to be able to hook in, this is not the case if you only define a `this.route('stories')`, see here under `resources` http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
Ember.ObjectController.extend({    

  showNew: function() {
    this.set('isNewVisible', true);
  }

});
```

instead of:

```
Ember.ArrayController.extend({    

  showNew: function() {
    this.set('isNewVisible', true);
  }
});
```

This guide might be helpful - [Ember.js - Templates](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/).

Comment: I was pretty sure I'd given this a whirl, but just to make sure I made this change, but am getting the same error. I think ArrayController is the one I want to extend based on how it's interacting with the model, but it doesn't seem to affect this problem either way. Thank you!