# Similar to nothing handled the event ember

Tags: ember.js

i had a look at this:

[Ember.js Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'addSite'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876275/ember-js-uncaught-error-nothing-handled-the-event-addsite)

and

[Ember.js Action error: "Nothing handled the event"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550592/ember-js-action-error-nothing-handled-the-event)

but dont know enough to see where mine is wrong, i have:

route.js:

```
 Todos.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('todos', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('active');
    this.route('completed');
    });
  });

  Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend ({
    model: function () {
      return this.store.find('todo');
    }
  });

 Todos.AboutRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
    return [{rate:100,qnty:1},{rate:101,qnty:1},{rate:102,qnty:1},{rate:103,qnty:1},{rate:104,qnty:1}];
   }
 });
```

then in index.html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="about">
{{#each}}
    {{input value=qnty min="1" max="9999999" type="number" disabled=true}}
    <button {{ action "increase" this}}>
      Up
    </button>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

then in about_controller.js:

```
Todos.AboutController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    increase: function(item) {
      var qnty = (Ember.get(item,'qnty'));
      console.log(qnty);
      Ember.set(item,'qnty',++qnty);
    }
  }
 });
```

i also get the error:
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'increase'.

can some one help please?
thanks

Comment: Could you share a jsbin? In your example I can't see where the `about` route is wired, and that could make a difference. http://emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: i do not understand? maybe that is what i am missing? what am i supposed to have still? i do not know how to share in jsbin, still  must find out how :) sorry

Comment: like so??? http://jsbin.com/aHIHAJax/1/

Comment: i am trying to incorporate  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IDiKaQe/1/edit into what i have already :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work for me: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EcOdEmo/1/edit

I did notice that your templates and routes indicate there is an `about` route but I didn't see that in your router. I updated the router to include that and your existing logic worked:

```
Todos.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('todos', { path: '/' }, function() {
    this.route('active');
    this.route('completed');
  });
  this.resource('about');
});
```